# Question on join where one column one side is null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables, storing candidates and their grades. A simple join can get all the candidates and their grades, by matching IDs etc.

e.g:

```
Alan    C
George  A
```

etc.. However:

```
Nina
```

The grade for Nina is null because she did not take the exam.

How can I get output like the following?

```
Alan   C
George A
Nina
```

So still get Nina, even though she did not take the exam. I've tried null checks and then performing something, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You want to use a left join.

```
select c.name, coalesce(g.grade,'')
    from candidate c
        left join grade g
            on c.candidate_id = g.candidate_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `left join`. For example:

```
 select c.name, g.grade
 from candidates c
 left join grades g on g.candidateid=c.id
```

A left join always lists all rows on the "left" side of the join - in this case, candidates. On rows where the candidate has no entry in the grades table, all columns that are filled from that table will be null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a left join for that.