# What to replace left join in a view so i can have an indexed view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, indexed

I have normalized tables in a database and to denormalize it, I created a view out of two tables. When I tried to create a clustered index on the view, it wouldn't let me, as the view was created with a left outer join. I used a left join because I want the null values to show up in the resulting view, much like how it was suggested in this earlier post.

[Question on join where one column one side is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119966/question-on-join-where-one-column-one-side-is-null)

The table structure and relationship is very much similar to what was described in the above link.

I seemed to hit a wall here as I couldn't convert my left join into an inner join, as that would exclude all records with null values on any of the joined columns. My questions are:

1. Why is indexing not allowed on outer or self joins?
2. Are there any performance hits on this kind of un-indexed view?
3. Anyone knows any workaround to this problem?

I've just finished a SQL Server course yesterday so don't know how to proceed. Would appreciate any comments. Cheers.

Comment: Do you need columns from the OUTER table?

Comment: If you really need the indexed view, you can create the (indexed) INNER JOIN one. Then you can LEFT JOIN the original (left side) table to this view to get the wanted output but with the performance gains of the indexed view.

Comment: @gbn & @ypercube: yeah, I need the column on the left outer table, and unfortunately, that is where I need to have the unique clustered index on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a "workaround" [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/indexedviewswithouterjoins/1884/) that involves check for `NULL` in the join and having a `NULL`  representation value in the table

NULL value

```
INSERT INTO Father (Father_id, Father_name) values(-255,'No father')
```

The join

```
JOIN [dbo].[son] s on isnull(s.father_id, -255) = f.father_id
```

Comment: @Damien, @gbn: Is it only me that this "workaround" seems awful? What happens to other queries that have `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rightTable`? You'll have to change them to correct the error (by 1) they'll give after the workaround?

Comment: @ypercube your right, it is awful and not really a workaround. But it is the only way to achive what you want. A better solution may be to index the underlying tables and skip the indexed view.

Comment: @Damien, as the old idiom goes: beggars can't be choosers

Answer (score 15):

Here is an alternative.  You want a materialized view of A not containing B.  That isn't directly available... so instead, materialize two views.  One of all A's and one of only A's with B's.  Then, get only A's not having B's by taking A except B.  This can be done efficiently:

Create two materialized views (mA and mAB) (**edit: mA could just be the base table**).
mA lacks the join between A and B (thus containing all A's period [and therefore containing those records WITHOUT matches in B]).
mAB joins between A and B (thus containing only A's with B's [and therefore excluding those records WITHOUT matches in B]).

To get all A's without matches in B, mask out those that match:

```
with ids as (
  select matchId from mA with (index (pk_matchid), noexpand)
  except
  select matchId from mAB with (index (pk_matchid), noexpand)
)
select * from mA a join ids b on a.matchId = b.matchId;
```

This should yield a left anti semi join against both your clustered indexes to get the ids and a clustered index seek to get the data out of mA you are looking for.

Essentially what you are running into is the basic rule that SQL is much better at dealing with data that IS there than data that ISN'T.  By materializing two sources, you gain some compelling set based options.  You have to weigh the cost of these views against those gains yourself.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a good workaround. What you can do about this is to create a real table from the view and set indexes on that. This can be done by a stored procedure that is called regularly when data is updated.

```
Select * 
into <REAL_TABLE>
From <VIEW>

create CLUSTERED index <INDEX_THE_FIELD> on <REAL_TABLE>(<THE_FIELD>)
```

But this is only a noteworthy approach if data isn't updated every few seconds.

Comment: It's a good solution. There is no need to update whole table every time. We can write trigger and update only changed rows.

Comment: As much as I *dislike* manual table updates.. stuff can be 'lost' easily.. this can be viable in certain situations.

Comment: Problem for batch operations, performance would be slow. Record update delete needs to be taken care as well, adds more maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Logically you are making two separate queries.  'A LEFT JOIN B' is just shorthand for '(A JOIN B) UNION A'

The first query is table A inner joined to table B.  This gets an indexed view, since this is where all the heavy lifting is done.

The second query is just table A where any of the join columns are null.  Make a view that produces the same output columns as the first query and pads them with nulls.

Just union the two results before returning them.  No need for a workaround.

Comment: This still won't work as INDEX'es aren't allowed in views that use the keywords UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT

Comment: Try it before declaring it won't work. A `UNION` of views *can* use the indices on the underlying views.

Comment: I just tried it and it's NOT possible to have an indexed view which uses UNION. Check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx#Restrictions

Comment: Create index view C for A JOIN B, then use normal view for C union A.

Answer (score -1):

I'll work on an answer to 1, but for now:

[2]. The view will be no more nor less performant than the equivalent query on the udnerlying tables. All the usual advice applies about having covering indexes, preferably an index on the joined columns, etc.

[3]. There's no real workaround. Most of the restrictions on indexed views exist for very good reasons, once you dig into them.

I'd just create the view, generally, and do no more, unless there was a specific performance problem.

I'll try to add an answer for 1 once I've reconstructed it in my own mind.

Comment: Lazyness from MS programmers to construct indexed views for `a LEFT JOIN b LEFT JOIN ... LEFT JOIN z` ?

Comment: @ypercube - most of the restrictions exist because they allow the indexed view to be maintained without having to perform full table scans for one or more base tables (e.g. why the only aggregates allowed are SUM, and then only if COUNT_BIG is also included), or perform other expensive operations.

Comment: Thanks for answering my other questions. Cheers.

Comment: Except a LEFT JOIN (at least with some join condition restrictions) doesn’t require any more index scans more than an INNER JOIN. Not supporting this basic LEFT JOIN scenario makes Indexed Views garbage for extending schemas: so in this case it’s a Feature/Functionality Defect.

Comment: > The view will be no more nor less performant than the equivalent query on the underlying tables. 
Urm no

Comment: @Simon_Weaver - what's your basis for believing otherwise? Views in SQL are much like macros in other programming languages - by the time a query is being optimized, the distinction between using the view or using the underlying tables has been eliminated.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever appreciate your reply (despite my snarky response after 12 years). The reason I said that was because OP is specifically talking about **indexed views** where the performance can be massively better. Agree that a view by itself should behave the same (although you can be worse off it you don't understand the nuances of things like NO EXPAND), but once indexed it's a completely different story. For example I have an indexed view for 'OrdersSearch' which can search on fields pulled from several tables. Then you can add indexes on the indexed view and the query is instant.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver - question 2, which I was answering, is/was "Are there any performance hits on this kind of **un-indexed** view?"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry for being an unbeliever. My mistake in misreading.